# How to bind a path source to MediaElement UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to bind a mp4 video into MediaElement, but just Works if I use absolute source in XAML like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaSimple" 
          Source="Videos/video1.mp4" 
          Width="400" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

I tried to do this :

```
 <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" Orientation="Vertical">
             <MediaElement  AutoPlay="True"  Width="150" Height="150"  IsLooping="True" Source="{Binding way}" />
             </StackPanel>
```

and my Class:

```
public class Paths
{
    public Uri Way { get; set; }
}
```

and my code behind:

```
public void Fill()
    {
        lista.Add(new Paths
        {
            Way = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/teste.mp4",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),   
        });
```

is not working at all,just work if I do XAML!

Comment: Excluding a typo in Way vs way your code seems ok. Please explain how you set the DataContext of the StackPanel and if you fire a NotifyPropertyChanged event when you update the list.

Comment: i tried to follow the same logic as to biding a normal Image, i don't have NotifyPropertyChanged, just a simple list! GridView.ItemSource = List;

Comment: If you don't implement NotifyPropertyChanged then how does the GridView know it's source has been updated. I suggest you simplify your test project further. Use only one MediaElement without the gridview and see if the binding works there.